# the "done" message after a &-command is not displayed right away, but after a user action. Why?

Tags: bash, sleep

I do a `sleep 3 &` and the "done" message is displayed as part of the `ps` command, not right on the console. It doesn't have to be `ps`. Any command after the `sleep` is done will have an extra line at the end with the "done" message. Why is that?

OS is centos-7.0, downloaded with vagrant.

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sleep 3 &
[1] 2838
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1871 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 2838 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep
 2840 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1871 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 2841 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
[1]+  Done                    sleep 3
[vagrant@localhost ~]$
```

If I do `ls > ls.txt` the "done" message doesn't go to the file. It is displayed on the console.
If I click enter after 3 secs, the message is displayed. Is it in some kind of cache? What happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "*Done*" message is not managed by the process you executed, but by `bash` itself to notify you about the end of a background job. That is why it provides the message when there is some console activity.

In `bash`, you can use :

- `set +m` (`monitor`) to remove this kind of messages if you do
  not want to see them.
- `set -b` (`notify`) to display the messages without any delay.

Answer (score 3):

[`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc25) says:

```
   The  shell  learns immediately whenever a job changes state.  Normally,
   bash waits until it is about to print a prompt before reporting changes
   in  a  job's status so as to not interrupt any other output.  If the -b
   option to the set builtin command is enabled, bash reports such changes
   immediately.   Any  trap  on  SIGCHLD  is  executed for each child that
   exits.
```